# Time function for an equivalent circuit

Tags: time, equivalent-circuit

In the IEEE magazine 6. NO. 3. JULY 1991 ***A Novel  Soft-Switching Full-Bridge DC/DC Converter: Analysis, Design  Considerations, and Experimental Results at 1.5 kW, 1OOkHz*** the following converter has the active state when any of the pair of transistors S1-S4 and S2-S3 are on.

[image]

C1 and C2 represents the parasitic capacitance ( Snubber, Trafo, etc ).

The converter has the following equivalent circuit for the passive state, the state in which no power is transferred through the Transformer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSfb3X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All the energy needed to charge the capacitance must be accounted for and the the author came up with the following time function for voltage across C<sub>1</sub>. What was his approach to it?

$$\begin{aligned}
V_{C1}(t) =& V'_O \frac{L_m}{L_m+L'_O}(1-\cos{\omega t}) \\
-& (I_m+I'_P)\sqrt{\frac{L_1+L_C+L_m||L'_O}{C_1}}\sin{\omega t} \\
+& V_{in}\cos{\omega t}
\end{aligned}$$

**EDIT: Franc enlightened me! Thank you!**

Comment: Who was the author? What was the paper?

Comment: To make it a better question, please edit it and tell us which parts of the function are unclear. The function is a sum of three terms, so, hopefully, you understand at least *some* of them, or at least some of the factors (things on either side of multiplication signs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the applied voltage has a sinusoidal time trend with pulsation ω and unit amplitude and that the initial conditions are zero, the calculation of the voltage across the capacitor is simple:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I made sense of it. My only question is : where does "sLo" disappear in the first equation? It seems that only the parallel xL ( inductive reactance ) are computated.

Comment: @i33SoDA Thanks, I had missed it.

Comment: Thank you again so much. You really helped me understand!! I very appreciate it!